# on dropdown select show n% of inputs

Tags: python-3.x

im trying to show a dropdown input based on the selected item in a "main" dropdown.

dropdown main is numberer from 0 to 5

i need that on selection of for example 3 it opens bellow 3 dropdown inputs

this can easily be done with jquery but im making a small app 100% python

this is what i got so far

```
   labdrop = Label(frmConf,width="18", text="Test:", anchor='w')
   labdrop.pack(side=LEFT)
   options = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5',]

   clicked = StringVar()
   clicked.set(options[0])

   drop = OptionMenu(frmConf, clicked, *options, command=slotstypes)
   drop.pack(anchor=W)


def slotstypes():
  i=int(1)
  a = int(clicked.get(options))
  print(a)
  while i < a:
      labdrop = Label(frmConf, width="18", text="got it", anchor='w').pack(side=LEFT)
      i += 1
```

got this error

```
        a = int(clicked.get(options))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

thanks in advance

Comment: The function that you pass to OptionMenu must have one parameter. (Probably the option that was chosen)

Comment: @Lcj hi, thanks for the reply, dont think so, i tried that and still get slotstypes() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given.
i tried   drop = OptionMenu(frmConf, clicked, *options, command=slotstypes(clicked))

Comment: Made some changes, and i belive im closer now @Lcj

Answer (score 0):

done it

```
   labdrop = Label(frmConf,width="18", text="Test:", anchor='w')
   labdrop.pack(side=LEFT)
   options = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5',]

   clicked = StringVar()
   clicked.set(options[0])

   drop = OptionMenu(frmConf, clicked, *options, command=slotstypes)
   drop.pack(anchor=W)


def slotstypes():
  i=int(1)
  a = int(clicked)
  print(a)
  while i < a:
      labdrop = Label(frmConf, width="18", text="got it", anchor='w').pack(side=LEFT)
      i += 1
```